# What is the difference between Community College and Junior College (JUCO)?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

In American English, I've always heard Community College in academic conversations, but Junior College (or JUCO) in athletic conversations.  Such as:

*I went to community college before attending State University.*

*Cam Newton played for a junior college before joining the Auburn Tigers.*

Is there a difference between the two types of schools?  If there is no difference in the type of school, <s>are there reasons why Junior College/JUCO is used primarily in sports contexts?</s> any thought why I commonly hear JUCO only in a sports context, but community college in academic context?

Comment: Junior College is not, to my knowledge, used "primarily in sports contexts." There was a junior college in my neighborhood that had nothing to do with sports.

Comment: It's the same thing.

Comment: The junior college in my neighborhood was public, by the way, so I also don't necessarily agree with the tendency mentioned by @MarkBeadles in his answer.

Comment: @Clare based on your comment I decided to check the stats directly, see the edit to my answer.

Comment: As with the difference between *university* and *college* and *institution* that has been hashed to death here, any historical distinctions have been swept away and it is largely a matter of tradition versus marketing.

Comment: @Clare I edited my question to emphasize my anecdotal experience.  What I really mean is, whenever I hear about athletes transferring from a 2 year school, ESPN and other national outlets almost exclusively use "JUCO/junior college".  But in my life experience (Ohio and New England), I have only ever encountered a community college as a learning institution.  So this is where the disconnect arose for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are just [different terminology for essentially the same thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_colleges_in_the_United_States#Terminology_and_control), which has evolved a little over time. "[Junior Colleges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junior_college#United_States)" tend to be a *private* 2-year institutions, and "Community Colleges" tend to be *public* 2-year institutions, but that's not a hard and fast rule. You'll also see the terms "Technical College", "[City College](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_Colleges_of_Chicago)", "County College", depending on where you live.

Edited to add:

It looks like "Community College" is currently much more common that "Junior College" as a name. Per the [US National Center for Education Statistics](https://nces.ed.gov/collegenavigator/), there are only 17 institutions with "Junior" in their name, of which 10 are private. However, there are over 500 institutions with "Community" in their name.